# looping over all arguments of a function in C++

Tags: c++

I want to do identical processing to a bunch of arguments of a function. Is there a way to loop over all arguments ? I am doing it the way represented in following code, but want to see if there is a compact way to do this.,

```
 void methodA(int a1, int a2, int b1, double b2){   
        //.. some code 
        methodB(a1, f(a1));
        methodB(a2, f(a2));
        methodB(b1, f(b1));
        methodB(b2, f(b2));
        // more code follows ...

   }

int f(int a){
      // some function. 
   return a*10;
}

double  f(double b){
   return b/2.0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can instead pass a pointer to an array, or a structure containing an array, which you can iterate directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use variadic templates:

```
template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void methodAHelper(T && t, Args &&... args)
{
  methodB(t, f(t));
  methodAHelper(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void methodAHelper() { }

template <typename ...Args>
void methodA(Args &&... args)
{
  // some code
  methodAHelper(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  // some other code
}
```

You can possibly get rid of the `&&` and the forwarding if you know that your `methodB` call doesn't know about rvalue references, that would make the code a bit simpler (you'd have `const Args &...` instead), for example:

```
methodAHelper(const T & t, const Args &... args)
{
  methodB(t, f(t));
  methodAHelper(args...);
}
```

You might also consider changing `methodB`: Since the second argument is a function of the first argument, you might be able to only pass the first argument and perform the call to `f()` *inside* the `methodB()`. That reduces coupling and interdependence; for example, the entire declaration of `f` would only need to be known to the implementation of `methodB`. But that's depends on your actual situation.

Alternatively, if there is only *one* overload of `methodB` whose first argument is of type `T`, then you could just pass a `std::vector<T>` to `methodA` and iterate over it:

```
void methodA(const std::vector<T> & v)
{
  // some code
  for (auto it = v.cbegin(), end = v.cend(); it != end; ++it)
    methodB(*it, f(*it));
  // some more code
}

int main() { methodA(std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4}); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, the concept you're looking for is called a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function).

Comment: It does have the drawback that it makes the arity non-fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are trying to do. The simplest thing might to revisit your function and see if it can take an array or std::vector as an argument. Might be much simpler that going the variadic route

Comment: it is a combination of ints and doubles so array or vector can not be used. I can possible use struct, but wanted to see if there is any compact way to do this.